# Scrolling the result table in data-explorer horizontally does not scroll the header, too

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, data-explorer, scrolling

I just had a look at this query [What posts have I edited that were not mine?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1010/what-posts-have-i-edited-that-were-not-mine). Its result is a quite wide table (more than twice the screen width with my browser), so horizontally scrolling is necessary.

But if I do this, the header fields do not scroll with the rest of the table. This is annoying, as I now don't know how the fields on the right side are even called.

[image]

This is on Opera 11.50 (Ubuntu 11.04).

Comment: Obviously you just need a bigger monitor. Forward a copy of this to your company's purchasing director. They won't be able to tell that it isn't a database table you need for work.

Comment: This is my home monitor ... I would have to forward to myself. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed on the live site, slick grid has been updated to latest.

Answer (score 5):

This is an Opera-specific [bug in SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/68). Looks like it's been fixed, so hopefully someone will update the version used by the Data Explorer in a future deploy.